# Debugging Pypy3

Tags: debugging, python-3.5, pypy, notimplementedexception

With the release of pypy3.5, I want to try running a python3 project in pypy. Doing so, I hit the following error:

```
RPython traceback:
  File "pypy_interpreter.c", line 38718, in BuiltinCodePassThroughArguments1_funcrun_obj
  File "pypy_module_cpyext_2.c", line 62299, in wrap_del
Fatal RPython error: NotImplementedError
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am unable to figure out what is causing this problem. For example, running the program in the python level `pdb` debugger does not break when the exception is raised.

What are technique for debugging pypy to understand what feature I'm using that's not implemented so that I can try to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug.  Please report it on https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues?status=new&status=open .